# Fail2ban multiple actions

Tags: iptables, fail2ban, jails

I am trying to create a jail for fail2ban, where upon a regex match I want to block the source IP from reaching either port 80 or 443 on my server.

I've tried variations of this:

```
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
         iptables[name=HTTPS, port=https, protocol=tcp]
```

but keep getting errors.  Lots of googling has turned up different suggestions that I can't make work.  Can someone show how one action can create two iptables rules? (or equivalent for what I'm trying to achieve)

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the same action name twice in the same jail.
Here it's "iptables".
Note that `name=` is the parameter name which is action oriented (action runtime parameter, in case of iptables it is a part of chain like f2b-), but not the action name itself.

To overcome this you need to introduce different actname:

```
action = iptables[actname=HTTP, name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
         iptables[actname=HTTPS, name=HTTPS, port=https, protocol=tcp]
```